# Does anyone know this part? I looks like a capacitor

Tags: capacitor, identification, components

The text says *10+ 20J*.
Does anyone have an idea what part it is and where I can get it or replace?

[image]

Comment: Can you put a bigger image so that we can see its designator?

Comment: if you do not know what it is, then how do you know that it needs to be replaced?

Comment: Some good study material: https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/electronic_components/capacitors/capacitor-codes-markings.php.

Comment: @jsotola Since it is a tantalum cap, you know that they need to be replaced once they have exploded :)

Answer (score 3):

It is a tantalum electrolytic capacitor, 10 uF 20V 5% tolerance. The + sign indicates polarity.

Comment: They  are often called "Tantalum drop capacitors"

Answer (score -2):

Looks like a 10volt, 20 microfarad, with a 5% tolerance, tantalum capacitor.

EDIT:  I found one with similar markings and tested it, and the other folks are right. The tolerance code after the voltage threw me off.

Comment: Or 10uF / 20 V cap?

Comment: I assumed since the J was the tolerance then the 20 had to be the value.

Comment: I would delete this answer if I were you.

Comment: @andy  Why?  If this is wrong then it might help someone else.

Comment: Your call @MikeSchroedel

Comment: So the voltage is the bottom number, right?  Then, why not just say that?